# Priority of parallel stages

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative pipeline parallel block, it is possible to specify multiple stages to execute in parallel on agents with the same node.

Let's say we have 3 stages defined and only two nodes available.

Stage A: 2 hrs
Stage B: 2 hrs
Stage C: 4 hrs

I want to be sure that stage C starts first, because then the total execution time will be 4 hrs. If A and B start first, then total execution will be 6 hours.

Is there any way to ensure Stage C is given priority to start first when all three stages are started using a parallel block?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to do this?

Comment: It has been a while, but I believe that the order they are declared in is the order they start.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a hack that should work - run them all in parallel just add sh 'sleep 5m' in A and B stage. Just ensure that you have at least 3 executors on node you run it ;)

But still if you run them all in parallel it should be only 4 hours not 6 hours.

Comment: This makes no sense. The sleep won't solve anything. The whole point of this is starting them in the right order if you *don't* have enough executors to start all parallel stages.